# Android recorded Video Filtering ( change color effect of recorded video )

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, video-processing, android-sdk-tools

i want to develop such a apps in that,

```
     - i record the video,
     - after that i want to video can be filter in different color,
     - like capture video display with our custom color, like in instagram application,
     - and then that video send to other,
```

i have much googled but didn't not find exact, after finding much, i find that it do through OpenCV or by ndk,

there are no possible simple way through Android-sdk only ?, if not then how to go with ndk , also in ndk i much googling but not find about video filtering,

so any one give a right way or any example related to this ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: See "show + capture camera" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: hello @fadden , i need your one help,this all work on all camera surface view , but in my app first i record the video and then i want to filter that in different color,so, please you can help me to how to it help in recorded video ?, in during camera preview it record well , but after normal recording then i want to affect to it in my videoview , so how to do for that ?

Comment: The "show + capture" activity works by capturing each preview frame and rendering it twice.  The frame sent to the display gets filtered, while the frame sent to the video encoder doesn't.  You'd need to perform the filtering in the encoder path as well.  See `handleFrameAvailable()` in TextureMovieEncoder.java.

Comment: after your comment i succeed to find : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/sample-codes-for-video-3d-on-android